# Adding document level JavaScript to PdfResultStamper using iTextSharp

Tags: pdf, itext

I am trying to add a document level JavaScript function to a PDF document using iTextSharp. I am adding the function to the document via a PdfStamper per some of the documentation I have found. The line in particular is:

```
_pdfResultStamper.JavaScript = GetJS();
```

The GetJS just returns a string of JavaScript that I copied from the prototype function I wrote in Acrobat Pro. This isn't the exact function but its close enough to get the idea of what I am doing:

```
public string GetJS()
{
    return "function sayHello(fieldObj){" +
                 "app.alert(fieldObj.value);" +
            "}";
}
```

When I open the generated PDF I do not see this function anywhere in the document JS (even when I choose "Edit All JavaScripts" in Acrobat).

Later on I am adding several checkboxes to the PDF form and binding to their mouseup events to call sayHello. This code does get added to the PDF as expected.

```
                PdfFormField Field = checkbox.CheckField;
                Field.Action = PdfAction.JavaScript("sayHello(event.target);", _pdfResultStamper.Writer);
```

However nothing happens (obviously) because the global/document level function is not present.

How do I go about adding the sayHello function at the document level so all the checkboxes can call it? I have tried a couple of other approaches and nothing seems to write the global function to the resulting PDF.

Comment: *it was being lost when we copied the PDF page into the actual document. This is supposition, though* - that sounds very plausible... `PdfCopy` copies page ranges but not document level JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you find that documentation? Did you check the official documentation?

I've written an [AddJavaScriptToForm](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=238) example for my book. In that example, the `addJavaScript()` method is used. As you're using iTextSharp (C#) instead of iText (Java), you'll want to consult [the official C# examples](http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C13). You'll need to adapt the relevant line more or less like this:

```
_pdfResultStamper.Writer.AddJavaScript(GetJS());
```

Comment: That was one of the examples I looked at. To be frank I have looked at many examples and they all seemed to have the same approach of either _pdfResultStamper.JavaScript = GetJS() or _pdfResultstamper.Writer.AddJavaScript(GetJS()) but none of them work. For example: http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter13&ex=AddJavaScriptToForm. I eventually worked around it by adding the JS via a PdfCopy.AddJavaScript function call.

Answer (score 0):

So I think my situation is compounded by how we are building our PDF document. In short we are building several PdfStamper objects, running the stamper through a template binding process to populate fields and format some things, dumping the stamper into a memory stream collection, then using PdfCopy to coalesce the streams into one PDF document using PdfCopy with each memory stream representing one page in the PDF. I think when adding the JavaScript to the PdfStamper it was being lost when we copied the PDF page into the actual document. This is supposition, though. I solved the issue by using the PdfCopy.AddJavaScript() function when coalescing into one document.